# How to adapt Device.OnPlataform to switch(Device.RuntimePlatform)?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile

I need to "update" the following code:

```
namespace Pizzahouse.Pages
{
public class IndexPage : ContentPage
{
    public IndexPage()
    {
        Title = "Index";

        var telephone = new Button()
        {
            Text = "Call",
            WidthRequest = 50,
        };
        telephone.Clicked += (sender, e) => Device.OpenUri(new Uri("tel://123465789"));

        Content = new ContentView()
        {
            Content = new StackLayout()
            {
                Children = {
                    new Image
                    {
                        Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
                        Source = Device.OnPlatform(
                            ImageSource.FromFile("PizzaIcon.png"),
                            ImageSource.FromFile("PizzaIcon.png"),
                            null)
                    }, telephone
                }
             }
        };
    }
}
}
```

I need to insert an image, but Xamarin.Forms says that the Device.OnPlataform() method is obsolete, and it says that I should use switch(Device.RuntimePlatform).

This exact code works, so what do you suggest? Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Source = (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.WinPhone) ? null : ImageSource.FromFile("PizzaIcon.png");
```